# How to determine two angles formed when a perpendicular is dropped

Tags: geometry

In the following image, when we drop a perpendicular $XZ$, cutting $XZ$ at $O$', the angles formed (as given in a solved example) are $\angle OYX = 60^{\circ}$ and $\angle OYZ = 45 ^{\circ}$. Why so?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropping the perpendicular splits your original triangle into two 'new' triangles, both right-angled triangles: triangle $XOY$ and triangle $ZOY$ (draw a picture!). Since $YO$ is perpendicular to $XZ$, you know the values of $\angle XOY$ and $\angle ZOY$, and you know that the sum of the angles in each of the 'new' triangles is $180^{\circ}$, so... (I expect you can finish the rest for yourself).

Comment: God I feel so stupid! Thank you!

Comment: No problem. For future reference, on this site, it's customary to 'accept' the most useful answer by giving it the little green tick.

Comment: Was just doing that, a minute left.

Answer (score 0):

By dropping YO perpendicular to XZ,we get two triangles the angles thus formed are 90 degrees. So sum of angles is 180 degrees.
Angle XYO will 60 degrees and angle ZYO will become 45 degrees.
See the figure....